# Are our actions outcome of mind & body or of soul?

Tags: scripture, karma, atma, body, mind

I would like to understand this thing from our scriptures point of view:

```
Are our actions outcome of our mind & body or of soul (Atma)?
```

Please do cite authentic references with your answers.

Comment: Actions are outcome of all 3. Soul is the agent, but it needs a mind and body to act.

Comment: Prakriti kriyamanani guna karmani sarvashah - check this gita verse. Actions happen by default in nature of prakriti. Ur vasanas samskaras tendencies dictate the movement of mind and hence actions.  The Atma is akarta. Non doer. In that verse krishna says due to ahamkars Atma thinks itself as doer. But actions are purely related to prakriti and Atma is non doer and just a witness.

Comment: Drop sense of doership. You won't incur karma but carry on what's to be done.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti can you plz tell from which chapter is this verse?

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti, a witness never has to bear consequences of actions that happen. but the atma does. One of the first few verses of Brahma Sutra says that Jiva is the doer, because if he is not the doer, then there is no use of Shastras dictating what to do and what to avoid - so we either have to choose between Shastras being useless or Jiva being the doer. Hence we choose the latter.[

Comment: @Just_Do_It its in Karma yoga chapter I think. Even in 13th chapter of verse 29 Krishna again emphazies that Prakriti alone does while Atma is akarta.

Comment: Sorry its 30th verse in 13th chapter

Comment: its like vicious cycle linga deha is made of prakurti, according linga deha the corresponding desire.. iccha comes out of jiva, out several iccha god only fulfils those iccha are deemed fit according to his will. not the jivas will.. this desires which are coming out jiva swabhava also.. this eventually leads to permenant hell or moksha based on jiva swabhava

Comment: @PrasannaR, there is no such thing as permanent hell for an atma. hell is permanent as long as creation comes and goes, but an atma is not doomed to it forever.

Comment: It's like saying only positive no is there in mathematics @ram even for natural numbers starting from 0 if you take any no above 0 to count decreasing order till 0you need -ve no to say moksha infinite time and andhamas is finite than the whole creation is unbalanced and collapse on its own

Comment: @PrasannaR, yes + & - are infinite. But + & - don't equate to moksha and naraka. + & - equate to moksha and samsara. we have been in samsara for infinite time all of which is negative. Both hell & heaven fall under this negative, because both are bad compared to moksha. heaven is simply closer to zero, while hell is farther from zero. the concept of a permanent 'hell' or 'naraka' is only in Islam/Christianity. Unless by 'hell' they too mean 'samsara' in which case, it is 'permanent' in principle, but not permanent for an 'atma'.

Comment: @PrasannaR, Samsara is Nitya. But there are no nitya-samsaris (meaning at some point, i think, Moksha). Naraka and Svarga (being part of Samsara) are also Nitya. But there are no nitya svarga-vasis or nitya naraka-vasis (meaning, at some point, they switch back and forth between bhumi-svarga-naraka, all of which are within Samsara)

Comment: as per your argument moksha will be crowded and nasty because those we see who are haters of god will also be there along with us.. than that kind of moksha is not needed.. because as per bhagavad gita krishna clearly says ch 16 19-21 andhamas is there for the demonic souls they wont get redeemed and for sure they wont reach moksha if you deny bhagavad gita please quote and pramana from vedas and sastra or bhagavad gita with authentic citication that all will attain moksha at the end of one creation cycle because this assumption which you are making is very audacious @ram

Comment: because of this assumption a person who is doing demonic activity and demonic need not change.. because moksha is any way gaurantee.. @ram from this assumption you can actually make what is the real intent of acharyans who had made this assumption.. that assumption should be coming from demonic mind

Comment: *"as per your argument moksha will be crowded and nasty because those we see who are haters of god will also be there along with us"* - that is not my argument at all. people who are haters of god will not get moksha.* "authentic citication that all will attain moksha at the end of one creation cycle"* - i did not say this either. *"because moksha is any way guarantee"* - it is guarantee, but the demonic people will not believe that. so they will not become complacent in their demonic ways. They will be inflicted so much pain that they will not believe it, hence they'll mend their ways.

Comment: Basically body is channelizing of your soul's previous Karma, because a jiva like common man or animal does not know its an aamta/soul in reality. Soul aka Purusha covered with shells of ego, mind and body aka Prakriti by the nature gives it a chance to work and prove oneself, evolve and improve through 84 thousand type of wombs/creatures available on earth. But only in human birth, one can realize one's true nature and attain Kaivalya. Actions is yours but environment is of nature like while playing a computer/mobile game, you make choices, win or lose but you havenot designed the game.

Answer (score 2):

Who does the actions is emphasized atleast twice in Bhagavad Gita by Shri Krishna that Prakriti alone does all the actions and it happens by default. But due to the deluded false ego, the Jiva assumes itself to be doer and thus incurs consequences of Karma.

> प्रकृत्यैव च कर्माणि क्रियमाणानि सर्वश: |
>   य: पश्यति तथात्मानमकर्तारं स पश्यति || 30||
>
> prakṛityaiva cha karmāṇi kriyamāṇāni sarvaśhaḥ
>
> yaḥ paśhyati tathātmānam akartāraṁ sa paśhyati
>
> Translation
>
> BG 13.30: They alone truly see who understand that all actions (of the body) are performed by material nature, while the embodied soul actually does nothing.

Krishna in this makes a confirmation that who understands all actions are particularly done by body and mind in accoradance with Guna, and the Dehi, Jiva doesnt do anything are the one who sees the knowledge.

Another verse here it is.

> प्रकृते: क्रियमाणानि गुणै: कर्माणि सर्वश: |
>
> अहङ्कारविमूढात्मा कर्ताहमिति मन्यते || 27||
>
> prakṛiteḥ kriyamāṇāni guṇaiḥ karmāṇi sarvaśhaḥ
>
> ahankāra-vimūḍhātmā kartāham iti manyate
>
> BG 3.27: All activities are carried out by the three modes of material nature. But in ignorance, the soul, deluded by false identification with the body, thinks itself to be the doer.

Here's another verse from Karma Yoga which says entire activities are carried on in accordance with Prakritis Gunas but the false ego makes the Jiva thinks itself as the doer.

If the Atma is non doer, why it incurs Karma? The Karma is incured as long as one owns doership of "I". This "I" is the ahankar, the ego. Its this identity of "I" experiences the sukha dukha, i.e happiness and sorrows as consequences of Karma but the Jiva wrongly identifies itself with the changing nature of prakriti.

The Shiva sutras also say "Atma Chittam" = the Individuality is the Mind. Thus, through the practice of Karma Yoga, one gives up the sense of doership and once the ahankara is dropped, the Atma Jnana dawns into such practitioners.

One cannot compare changing nature of prakriti with unchanging nature of Atma.

Comment: Aside that, now what is for enlightened ones? Those who are in into sadhana through any means of agamas, tantras, vedanta = as they advance in sadhana , the individuality which they are now will be disappeared as one advances. When individuality disappears what happens, the enjoyer and enjoyment, the bhokta of Karma is uprooted. When that is uprooted, the Jiva realizes its eternal nature and finally upon end of prarabdha attains the parama padam.

Comment: But thing is without soul, body & mind are nothing and all the karmas are carry forwarded to the next birth by the soul so in that case isn't soul the doer of all actions?

Comment: No. Doers of actions are karma indriyas jnana indriyas manas Buddhi and ahamkara which expects results of actions. And what dictates this movement of actions is your own samskara vasanas. Thus the Atma gives life for all these to function but it doesn't do anything. But due to maya what happens is "when there's anger emotion, it identifies itself with "Iam angry. "IAM happy.  Who is aware and is identifying with the changes? That is jivatma. Any changes in prakriti is noted by it and due to maya it identifies itself with change. Thats why jeeva seems to be doer but not

Comment: Patanjali yoga sutras also is good source to verify. When modifications of mind sre stopped Purusha is appreciated in its real nature. Just a different word but look at content.  As long as modifications of mind in ignorance is there seer identifies itself with changing.  When identification happens brinhs him to bondage.  Again karma.